# Cumulating value of previous row in Column FINAL_VALUE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms, window-functions

My table name is "fundt" and my question is:

> how to cumulative sum of previous row in Column FINAL_VALUE?"

I think it possible with cross join but I don't know how.

[image]

Comment: *Cumulative sum* of what? Please explain the computation rule for `final_year`, it is not obvious by looking at your data.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want window functions with a window frame:

```
select
    t.*,
    sum(final_value) over(
        order by it_month 
        rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding
    ) cumulative_final_value
    from mytable t
```

This gives you a cumulative `sum()` of previous rows (not including the current row), using column `it_month` for ordering. You might need to adapt that to your exact requirement, but this *seems* to be the logic that you are looking for.